# Rails: Multiple image upload at the same time with Dragonfly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, upload, nested-forms, dragonfly-gem

I'm using Dragonfly to upload images to model Photo which is associeted to others models. For example:

MODEL: Post

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :photos, dependent: :destroy

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :photos, allow_destroy: true,
                                reject_if: lambda {|attributes| attributes['image'].blank?}
```

MODEL Photo

```
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend Dragonfly::Model::Validations

  dragonfly_accessor :image

  dragonfly_accessor :image do
    after_assign { |img| img.encode!('jpg', '-quality 80') }
  end
```

It works fine, even when I change the input to upload multiple files at the same time

FORM VIEW:

works:

```
<%= f.fields_for :photos do |photo| %>
    <%= photo.file_field :image, class: "form-control"  %>
<% end%>
```

doesn't works:

```
<%= f.fields_for :photos do |photo| %>
    <%= photo.file_field :image, class: "form-control", multiple: true, name: 'photo[image]' %>
<% end%>
```

How can I upload multiple files at the same time to associeted model?

Thanks!

**UPDATE:**

I tried:

controller. Create action

```
   @post = Post.new(seminovo_params)
    params[:photos]['image'].each do |a|
      @photo = @post.photos.create!(:image => a)
    end
```

View

```
     <%= f.fields_for :photos, @post.photos.new do |photo| %>
        <%= photo.file_field :image, :multiple => true, name: "photos[image][]"  %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo need to define params and get those params this way

Your new method should contain

```
def new
 # Your new form object 
 @photo = @post.photos.build
end
```

In controller method use this

```
params[:photos]['avatar'].each do |a|
  @photo = @post.photos.create!(:image => a)
end
```

Your form should look like,

```
<%= form_for(@post, :html => { :multipart => true }) do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :photos do |p| %>
    <div class="field">
      <%= p.label :image %><br>
      <%= p.file_field :image, :multiple => true, name: "photos[image][]" %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"photos[image][]\"; filename=\"10395806_685294291596378_3110064580239039583_n.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">, #<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x00000006aa22f0 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20151124-7856-1ktvepw.jpg>, @original_filename="10475439_705162236276250_7487512119604520758_o.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"photos[image][]\"; filename=\"10475439_705162236276250_7487512119604520758_o.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">, #

Comment: The photo array looks like empty. I updated the code above.

Comment: You add new method. see my edits. and remove @post.photos.new from.

Comment: Not work yet. What is this 'avatar' parameter? And if I remove @post.photos.new, I get a input file for each file uploaded, plus a input file to upload a new image. I just want a input to upload a new photo or photos on form, its because I added a new parameter, it was a way I find to not appear many input files

Comment: Can you share repository url I can take a look?

Comment: A gist of controller and models https://gist.github.com/a14d37238ca6fd4fbf9c.git  and a gist of form https://gist.github.com/0d605b5ec440b2b96814.git

Comment: ops: https://gist.github.com/pailoro/a14d37238ca6fd4fbf9c https://gist.github.com/pailoro/0d605b5ec440b2b96814